# Fetch all the values of an attribute through NSPredicate in CoreData

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios5, xcode4.2, nspredicate

This question will sound like a newbie but i have gone through all threads for my solution which is still an issue for me. So i have an entity "LookUp" which has an attribute 'descrip'.
Now my question is i want to fetch all values of attribute 'descrip'.

Till now i have used all this queries:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"descrip == %@",[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"descrip == %@",@"descrip"];
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"descrip == %@",[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
```

if i fire a query

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"descrip == %@",@"Art Gallery"];
```

it returns me an array with the values associated with "Art Gallery". The 'descrip' attribute contains 250 values like "Art Gallery".

Please help it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"descrip == %@",@"%"];? Do you want only the unique values of descrip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NSPredicate** is used to limit your results to entities that adhere to a certain restriction - like you said, *descrip == @"Art Gallery"* will return all entities that have a *decrip* attribute set to *Art Gallery*.

In your case, you do not want to restrict the entities in your query. Just perform your query without any predicate, and all entities will be returned. Now just loop over the entities, and get all values of *descrip* into a **NSMutableSet** or **NSMutableDictionary**, and you have your list of *descrip* values.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to modify the fetch request, rather than a predicate. See ["Fetching Distinct Values" in Apple's Core Data Snippets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/fetchExpressions.html).

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = // Get the context.

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"LookUp" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"descrip"]];

// Execute the fetch.
NSError *error;
id requestedValue = nil;
NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (objects == nil) {
    // Handle the error.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the request

```
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:
  [NSArray arrayWithObject: @"descrip"];
```

But you'd still have to loop over the results array in order to grab the descrip values only.